# Extending linux root partition with unallocated space

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, linux-mint, gparted

I have set my PC to dual boot Linux and windows 10.

I have cut some space from my `C:/` partition in windows using some program.

now i want to extent the root Linux partition with that unallocated space, I am using **`GParted`** on a live USB but I am not able to do so,

the right click on root and selecting resize not detecting the free space!

What should I do

[image: Gparted now!]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move `sda3` and `sda5` down first, so that the free space is adjacent to `sda4`, which you can then resize.

Now move `sda5` down so the free space is adjacent to `sda6`, which you can then extend.

You should be able to set up all these operations in `gparted` before you apply them, but it will then take a long time.

This is an operation which could lose all your data if it goes wrong, so you **must** back up the entire disc drive first.

If this seems too daunting, consider creating a new `ext4` partition in the current free space, then choose a suitable mount point for it. It won't be as flexible as a larger partition, but it's a lot safer, quicker and easier to do.

Comment: thanks for answering, how much time, it will almost take? and I will not be able to backup => how risky is to proceed ? I mean does it usually goes wrong?

Comment: I have no idea how long - it will depend on disc and CPU speeds, but I would expect several hours. If you have backed up all your user data (and you are very silly if you haven't), then you will need to be prepared to re-install everything. I've not had a failure doing this sort of thing, though I've not tried anything quite as complex as this, but that is no indication. I certainly wouldn't do it without a drive back-up, and the cost of an external drive (~£70 for 2TB in UK) is small compared with the time and effort of rebuilding everything. You can never have too many back-ups.

Comment: if this is an MBR partition table (which seems likely) it won't be possible to create a new primary partition in the space between sda2 and sda3.  conversion to GPT might be possible but it's risky and will make Windows unhappy.

Comment: @quixotic - I assume it is GPT: there are already too many partititions for MBR.

Comment: @AFH look again.  sda4 is an *extended* partition, thus 5-8 are *logical* partitions inside it.  it could be an MBR-GPT hybrid, but afaik extended partitions aren't a defined partition type in GPT.

Comment: @quixotic - You may be right: I've never been able to create that many partitions on an MBR drive, so I assumed it had to be GPT, and although it's not normal to have an extended partition on GPT, I didn't think it was disallowed - it's not easy to check. You will see from my answer that I was well aware that `sda4` is an extended partition.